# Cannot capture events from custom component in NS6

Tags: nativescript

I am using NS 6.0 Core.  Testing on a physical Android device (have not tried this on iOS yet).

In a nutshell, I have nested components and in the inside component, I want to capture a custom event and pass it to the host component.

Inside component (called TopBar):

```html
<StackLayout padding="10" orintation="horizontal" loaded="onLoaded">
  <Label text="&#xe907;" class="wa" fontSize="24" vertcalAlignment="middle" tap="back" />
</StackLayout>
```

```js
import { StackLayout } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/stack-layout';
import { EventData } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view';

var stack: StackLayout;
let eventData: EventData = {
    eventName: "onBackEvent",
    object: stack
}

export function onLoaded(args) {
    stack = <StackLayout>args.object;
}

export function back() {
    stack.notify(eventData);
}
```

The host component

```js
import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page/page";
import { StackLayout } from "tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/stack-layout/stack-layout";
import { EventData, Observable } from "tns-core-modules/data/observable";

var model: Observable = new Observable();
var page: Page;

export function onLoaded(args: EventData) {
    page = <Page>args.object;

    var topBar: StackLayout = page.getViewById('topBar');
    topBar.on('onBackEvent', () => {
        console.log('go back');
    });

    page.bindingContext = model;
}
```

```html
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" xmlns:tb="components/shared/top-bar/top-bar" loaded="onLoaded" actionBarHidden="true">
    <GridLayout rows="*, 75" columns="*">
        <StackLayout class="page-content">
            <tb:TopBar id="topBar" height="50"></tb:TopBar>

        </StackLayout>
    </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

Any ideas on what I might be missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after hours of trial and error, I manage to make it work.

The issue is that when notifying the client, we have to declare the `EventData` object as such:

```js
let eventData: EventData = {
    eventName: "BackEvent",
    object: stack
}
```

Note that we capture the event by subscribing to `onBackEvent` but setting up the event name as `BackEvent`.  I am not sure why this works or where in the documentation it is written, but this change did the job.

If anyone has more information about this, please post it here so we can all learn.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

{N} [automatically trims](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/nativescript-core/ui/core/bindable/bindable.ts#L67) event names starting with `on`, hence `onBackEvent` will be recorded as `BackEvent` only. So notifying `onBackEvent` will not have any effect.

In my opinion it makes sense, also when I checked last time Angular didn't use to support event names prefixed with `on` with event binding. That could also be a reason they had to force this as a standard measure.